# Sequence of resources to be detached while terminating ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I was asked to write a boto3 python code for terminating the ec2 instances. what is the sequence of resources attached to the instance that need to be deleted first before the instance is deleted. is it network resources to be detached first and deleted and then go to volumes etc. Please guide

Comment: You don't have to delete anything prior to terminating an ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to detach any of the components like network, storage etc., of the EC2 instance before termination.

If you wanted to prevent storage that has critical data from deletion, set the EBS storage flag "**delete on termination**" to "**false**" and then terminate your EC2 instances.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. but i see that in order to delete an Ec2 instance, we first have to delete the EBS volume attached to that , then delete that. similarly if i have to delete the VPC, first delete every resource running inside that VPC  and then delete . This is what iam trying to find. a sequence of resources to be deleted first to delete an ec2 instances

Comment: I will change my Question, as you said i was able to terminate the ec2 instance with boto3 code but if i have to delete a Subnet first, it throws me an error saying there are dependencies associated with them. first i have to clean them and delete the VPC. these dependencies is what iam trying to solve

Comment: to delete the Subnet, first you need to delete the ec2 instance, then only you can be able to delete other resources like subnet, VPC.

Comment: The order of deletion is EBS, EC2 instance, Subnet, VPC....

Comment: Great, let me do this.